# How to get textarea content with jquery

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am new to jquery. I got struck with some function, I have two textarea boxes, let us suppose

the first textarea id is first_ta 
the second textarea id is second_ta

```
<textarea id="first_ta" rows="2" cols="2"></textarea>
<textarea id="second_ta" rows="2" cols="2"></textarea>
```

**1.**  I want the content of first_ta in a **"p"** tag and the tag should be generated by jquery itself.

**2.** I want the content of second_ta in a **"div"** tag that should be generated by jquery and the div's id should be changed dynamically, if i repeat the process.

Please help me to find the solution for the above.

Comment: When do you want this to happpen ?

Answer (score 7):

> I want the content of first_ta in a
>   "p" tag and the tag should be
>   generated by jquery itself.

```
$('<p>').html($('#first_ta').val()).appendTo('body');
```

I want the content of second_ta in a "div" tag that should be generated by jquery and the div's id

```
// assuming you've got a variable genId defined somewhere in your code with a start 
// value of 1
$('<div>').html($('#second_ta').val()).attr('id', 'generated-id-' + genId++).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aron. I will try the code and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

The same as @Aren reply but just add encodeURIComponent for reading textarea value

```
$('<p>').html(encodeURIComponent($('#first_ta').val())).appendTo('body');

$('<div>').html(encodeURIComponent($('#second_ta').val())).attr('id', 'generated-id-' + genId++).appendTo('body');
```